# Ruby on Rails: How do you display "raw" erb tags in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I want to display `<%= @location.country %>` in views to the user. So if the user visits http://domain.com/tutorials/123, he'll see `<%= @location.country %>`. That is, Rails doesn't process that portion.

I'm thinking something along the lines of `<*= @location.country %>`, but of course that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try: `&lt;%= @location.country %>`?

Comment: What about `"<%= "<%= @location.country %>" %>"`? -- Not sure I understood the question actually...

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I tried MrYoshiji's idea, but got a "syntax error, unexpected '>'"

Comment: Did you try the &LT;?

Comment: I knew there was a ruby way to do it, but I forgot what it was. Edmund solved it below though. Thank you for your help mrbratch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a second %.

`<%%= @location.country %>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use html entities for the `<` (`&lt;`) and `>` (`&gt;`). So something like `&lt;%= @location.country %&gt;` will work.